# Pause/Stop AjaxDataSource Bokeh Stream

Tags: bokeh

I am able to set up my graph for streaming just fine. Here's the initialization:

```
self.data_source = AjaxDataSource(data_url='my_route', 
  polling_interval=1000, mode='append', max_size=300)
```

Now I want to 'pause' the polling of the AjaxDataSource. I couldn't find a way to do this in the documentation. I'm NOT running a bokeh server, so bokeh server solutions I am unable to use.

Comment: Have you been able to achieve what you are trying to do? I am having the same problems and need a solution for this. Tried doing a javascript callback to update the polling_interval to a very long time but Bokeh did not respect and kept polling for new data. I'll keep digging at it but I would appreciate if you were able to find a solution. I'll share mine if/once I am able to achieve the goal.

Comment: @bachree no unfortunately. I am still very interested in a solution to this. If you do end up coming up with something that works I would be very grateful. And I will share my solution if I find one.

Comment: I have ended up finding a hacky solution to this problem. What I have realized is the only setting that I can change for an AjaxDataSource with a javascript call back is the data_url. Therefore, I have formed a checkbox in Bokeh, added the source as an argument changed the data_url of the source when the checkbox is unselected to a dead url. That helped me prevent unneeded hits to my server but the browser still sends request to the dead server. Sorry, I don't have a concise and complete code for it but let me know if this is smt you are interested I can try to elaborate more.

Comment: @bachtree that's interesting. Did you try the answer below? How is that answer different from your solution? The other piece of the puzzle is how to RESET the graph? Let's say I am appending a lot of data from the stream, but then I want to change the stream to a new data source and remove all of the old data. Have you found a way to add that functionality? For me that's the thing that I need the most.

Comment: I haven't tried your solution since if I understood it correctly a request is still made to the URL and I simply did not want to put any load on the server when I pause the AJAXdataSource. For your case, I would probably try setting the each array in the data source to an empty array after resuming. So, I'm thinking smt along the lines of: 1)User unchecks the checkbox and data_url is set to a dead url
2)User checks the box and data_url is restored to the right url and a loop goes through each array in the data source and empties them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with one possible solution: just return empty data set to the function that is appending the data via AjaxDataSource. So in the example above, the my_route function would look something like this:

```
def my_route:
    if not self.is_paused:
        data = normal_data_to_graph
    else:
        data = []

    return data
```

Comment: This seems ok for now. Adding a pause feature would be a good idea as well as a straightforward task that'd good for a new contributor. I encourage you to file a GitHub issue to discuss it.

Answer (score 0):

Once you set the `polling_interval = None` in Python, it will not request it. In CustomJS, you can start the paused request. Here, the source is an `AJaxDataSource` instance.

```js
source.polling_interval = 1000; // the interval you want
source.intialized = false;
source.setup();
```